# Eslint problem in Reactjs with useEffect, in this case, how to do not need to put // eslint-disable-line

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

Well folks, I have a function that uses some variables within it. However, it should only be executed when a specific dependency on it is changed. in this case, the index state. How do I solve the problem without putting // eslint-disable-line. Thanks.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRows([])

    const max = index === pages ? data.length : index * range 

    for (let i = index * range - range; i < max ; i++) {
        setRows(oldElemets => [...oldElemets, data[i]])
    }

}, [index])
```

Comment: what is the concrete eslint error?

Comment: Do you want to execute it only on index change and not on data change?

Comment: I'm guessing that the lint is bitching about missing deps in useEffect array. Since you want to run this effect only on index change, is it possible to remove the calculation outside of useEffect? A function maybe..and then just call the function inside useEffect...